# Custom ExoPlayer control functions

Tags: android, exoplayer2.x

In my activity I play videos inside a ViewPager2, so that the user can swipe to get a new video. I want to change the ExoPlayer's fast forward and rewind button function to change the viewpager's position. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been searching for a good solution for this problem, but since I couldn't find any similar question that got answered I came up with this:

I removed everything from the exoplayer's layout except the seek bar. Then I placed those removed items below the PlayerControlView (the seek bar) in the fragment's layout file and give new ids to the buttons. This way I able to add onClickListeners to the buttons and from there I was able to change the item in the ViewPager.

exo_player_control_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_gravity="bottom" android:layoutDirection="ltr" android:background="#CC000000" android:orientation="vertical" tools:targetApi="28">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="4dp" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_position" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:paddingLeft="4dp" android:paddingRight="4dp" android:includeFontPadding="false" android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE" />
        <View android:id="@id/exo_progress_placeholder" android:layout_width="0dp" android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_height="26dp" />
        <TextView android:id="@id/exo_duration" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textSize="14sp" android:textStyle="bold" android:paddingLeft="4dp" android:paddingRight="4dp" android:includeFontPadding="false" android:textColor="#FFBEBEBE" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

fragment.xml:

```
...
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark">

                <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
                    android:id="@+id/play_view"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="300dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    app:surface_type="texture_view"
                    app:use_controller="false"/>

                <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerControlView
                    android:id="@+id/controls"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/play_view"
                    app:show_timeout="0" />

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:background="#CC000000"
                    android:layout_below="@id/controls">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/rew"
                        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Previous"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"/>

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/play"
                        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Play"
                        android:visibility="gone"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ffwd"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/rew"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/pause"
                        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Pause"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/ffwd"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/rew"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/ffwd"
                        style="@style/ExoMediaButton.Next"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="18dp"/>

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

In the viewpager's adapter, I pass a boolean to the fragment to check if the viewpager's current item is the last one

```
...
@Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
            boolean last=false;
            if (position == mDataBase.size()-1)
                last = true;
            VideoItem video = mDataBase.get(position);
            return VideoPlayerFragment.newInstance(video.getTitle(),last);
        }
...
```

And this is the fragment's code:

```
...

mForward = view.findViewById(R.id.ffwd);
mPlay = view.findViewById(R.id.play);
mRewind = view.findViewById(R.id.rew);
mPause = view.findViewById(R.id.pause);

...

if (getArguments().getBoolean(KEY_LAST)){
            mForward.setAlpha((float) 0.5);
        }

        mPlayer.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onIsPlayingChanged(boolean isPlaying) {
                if (isPlaying){
                    mPause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    mPlay.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }else{
                    mPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                if (playbackState == Player.STATE_ENDED){
                    mPause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mPlay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ended = true;
                }else
                    ended = false;
            }
        });


        mPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(false);
            }
        });

        mPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (ended){
                    mPlayer.seekTo(0);
                }
                mPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            }
        });
        mForward.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (!getArguments().getBoolean(KEY_LAST)){
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem()+1);
                }
            }
        });

        mRewind.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() < 2000 && mPager.getCurrentItem() != 0)
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(mPager.getCurrentItem()-1);
                else
                    mPlayer.seekTo(0);

            }
        });
```

I hope it helps somebody.